# Focussing lens placed after double slit experiment

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, lenses

How would the expression for the intensity distribution produced by a double slit on a screen change if a focussing lens of focal length $f$ were placed a distance $f$ in front of the screen?

Note: the general intensity of the double slit experiment is:
$$I=I_0\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi ax}{\lambda D}\right)\right)^2$$

Would the light just all pass through the focus, creating one bright spot on the screen and nothing else?

Comment: I have realised that my original assumption is incorrect-- the light entering the lens will not be parallel, so will not pass through the focus

Comment: If you use the lens to *image* the double slit on the screen, you'll find that each photon will land on the screen at one of two locations, corresponding to each of the two imaged slits.  It will look as if each photon definitely passed through just one slit, in seeming contradiction to the scenario where the lens is removed.

Answer (score 0):

The formula assumes that parallel rays from the two slits meet at a point on the screen.  Unless the distance to the screen is large relative to the slit width, then the screen should be at the focal point of a converging lens.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. The formula I included is for the general intensity distribution produced by a double slit experiment (which includes the assumption that the distance to the screen is large relative to the slit width). (I have edited the question to try and make this more clear)

Comment: Using a lens after the slits lets you bring the screen closer.  Using a lens before the slits lets you bring a line source closer.

Comment: If I leave the screen where it is, will the interference pattern just get more spread out then?

Comment: If the screen is not at the focal point of the lens, the image will go out of focus.